# how to write cron to show a script output in new terminal

Tags: linux, shell

Hi I want to show the output of a shell-script in the terminal, how can I do it, for example
script name showservices.sh contains follow text

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef
```

this will show the processes running. Now I have a file named firstcron.txt, code is below

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; $home/dilip/crontest/showservices.sh
```

Now put this in cron by below

```
crontab firstcron.txt
```

But it is not able to show the output of script in terminal. Please help me how can I do this

Comment: Which terminal ? If you have 500 terminals open on that machine - should *all* of them display the output ? That's a weird requirement! It would make much more sense (to me) to redirect the output to a logfile. It has the advantage that you'll be able to refer to it later.

Comment: no just open a new terminal and show output on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` is independent of X11 and so there is no guarantee that an X11 server is running when your `cron` job executes.  There is also no guarantee that there are not more than one X11 servers.  Even if X11 is running, there is no guarantee that the user you want to talk to is logged in, or is not logged in more than once, potentially on multiple X11 servers.  In other words, there is simply no straightforward mapping from `cron` to a terminal of the user who configured the job.  Moreover, a `cron` job lacks the authorization to connect to a running X11 session because that's how X11 was designed.

A typical design where such behavior is desired is a client/server model.  The `cron` job produces data which is served by the server process.  The user then sets up a client to talk to the server on the X11 session(s) s/he connected to where this service is desired.  The client process runs in the existing X11 session so it has the required credentials to open new windows and display information to the user.

For your simple requirement, as suggested in a comment, your `cron` job could simply overwrite a particular file, and the user could have a process monitoring that file.  This is the simplest imaginable form of IPC.

Most people would be happy with a single `xterm -e tail --follow=name /path/to/file` but if you really genuinely want windows jumping up in front of you while you are in the middle of something more important, try this.

```
#!/bin/sh
oldmd5=$(md5sum /path/to/file)
while true; do
    newmd5=$(md5sum /path/to/file)
    case $newmd5 in
        $oldmd5) ;;
        *) xterm -e less /path/to/file & oldmd5=newmd5 ;;
    esac
    sleep 60
done
```

Run this from your `.xsession` or similar.

Caution: You will want to have some sort of handbrake on this, or you could have 3,000-odd `xterm` windows on your desktop when you return after the weekend.

Comment: Ack contribution from @alfasin.